# I have a requirement to load data from azure cosmos db (json format) into snowflake. what are my options?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, snowflake-connector

I tried using nodeJS function to trigger on cosmos change feed and insert into snowflake table columns directly but that seems to be slow. please suggest any other options

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADF that has both snowflake and Azure Cosmos db Connector. Azure Cosmos db will be your source and Snowflake can be used as sink.

[Create a linked service to Azure Cosmos DB using UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-azure-cosmos-db-using-ui)

[Snowflake as sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#snowflake-as-sink)

Good part is Azure Cosmos db Change feed is now supported in ADF, so this can also be integrated through ADF.

[Native change data capture (CDC) - CosmosDB change feed is supported in ADF now](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/native-change-data-capture-cdc-cosmosdb-change-feed-is-supported/ba-p/3037011)